# Autodesk API: The system does not support this file format [.nwd file]

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm following an [Autodesk tutorial](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-to-obj/) on loading CAD files in the browser with WebGL, and am trying to convert an .nwd file I've uploaded to one of their buckets to an "OBJ".

When I run the POST request in step two of the tutorial above, however, I receive a 400 (full response below) that indicates `x-ads-troubleshooting: The system does not support this file format`, despite the fact that of the [Autodesk documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/navisworks-products/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Supported-file-formats-and-applications-for-Autodesk-Navisworks-2009-to-2012.html) indicates .nwd files are supported.

Here's the full path to my file (requires Oauth token): https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/gathering-a-bulding-bucket/objects/Yale_Residential_Colleges_Arch.nwd

When I added the item to the bucket, I was given the following objectId (which the docs also refer to as the source URN):

`"objectId" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:gathering-a-bulding-bucket/Yale_Residential_Colleges_Arch.nwd"`

I base64 encoded this string and removed the excess padding (the extra == characters at the end) per the documentation, which resulted in the following:

`dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2F0aGVyaW5nLWEtYnVsZGluZy1idWNrZXQvWWFsZV9SZXNpZGVudGlhbF9Db2xsZWdlc19BcmNoLm53ZA`

I'm now trying to convert this nwd file to an OBJ with the following command:

`curl -X 'POST' -H 'Authorization: Bearer OAUTHTOKENHERE' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' -d '{"input":{"urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2F0aGVyaW5nLWEtYnVsZGluZy1idWNrZXQvWWFsZV9SZXNpZGVudGlhbF9Db2xsZWdlc19BcmNoLm53ZA"},"output":{"formats":[{"type":"obj"}]}}'`

This command yields the following response:

```
* Connected to developer.api.autodesk.com (52.7.124.118) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: developer.api.autodesk.com
* Server certificate: Symantec Class 3 Extended Validation SHA256 SSL CA
* Server certificate: VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority
> POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job HTTP/1.1
> Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer OAUTHTOKENHERE
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 181
>
* upload completely sent off: 181 out of 181 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Fri, 09 Sep 2016 16:07:06 GMT
< Server: Apigee Router
< x-ads-app-identifier: platform-viewing-2016.08.01.1114.dbcc24a-production
< x-ads-duration: 525 ms
< x-ads-exception-id: c54954c5-dc74-4b09-961a-5eb7de82625b
< x-ads-startup-time: Wed Sep 07 01:40:23 UTC 2016
< x-ads-troubleshooting: The system does not support this file format.
< Content-Length: 61
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
{"diagnostic":"Failed to trigger translation for this file."}
```

Does anyone have any leads on what I might be overlooking? I'd be grateful for any help others can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look [at this list of supported translations](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/), you'll see that translation from .nwd to .obj is not supported, only to svf (which is used for [Viewer](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2)).

Comment: In case others land here wanting to convert nwd files, the following will convert to 2d and 3d representations in svf: curl -X 'POST' -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOURAUTHTOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' -d '{"input": {"urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Z2F0aGVyaW5nLWEtYnVsZGluZy1idWNrZXQvWWFsZV9SZXNpZGVudGlhbF9Db2xsZWdlc19BcmNoLm53ZA"},"output": {"formats": [{"type": "svf","views": ["2d","3d"]}]}}'